# Clean architecture using eShopOnWeb reference application - Entity Framework Core Performance Efficient Querying - Project only properties you need

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, clean-architecture

I'm reading up on Clean architecture on Microsoft Docs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture

I have also downloaded the eShopOnWeb reference application.

https://github.com/dotnet-architecture/eShopOnWeb

As seen in the image below and the reference implementation View Models are kept in the `Web` project and Dtos are in the `PublicApi` project.

[image]

Looking at how entities are converted to View Models and Dtos it looks like this:

```
var items = await _catalogBrandRepository.ListAsync();

response.CatalogBrands.AddRange(items.Select(_mapper.Map<CatalogBrandDto>));
```

or

```
var orders = await _orderRepository.ListAsync(specification, cancellationToken);

return orders.Select(o => new OrderViewModel
```

Code that sets up `IRepository` for `_catalogBrandRepository` and `_orderRepository`.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>));
builder.Services.AddScoped(typeof(IReadRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>));
```

or:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(IReadRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>));
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(EfRepository<>));
```

This works really well until performance is needed and I only want to project properties I need.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#project-only-properties-you-need

Given the set up I can not not select directly to a Dto given that the references will be wrong:

```
public class EfRepository<T> : RepositoryBase<T>, IReadRepository<T>, IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
{
    private readonly CatalogContext _dbContext;

    public EfRepository(CatalogContext dbContext) : base(dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public List<OrderViewModel> GetAllOrderViewModels()
    {
        //Does not work
        return _dbContext.Orders.Select(o => new OrderViewModel
        {
            OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
            OrderNumber = o.Id,
            ShippingAddress = o.ShipToAddress,
            Total = o.Total()
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

I could of course return the anonymous type as dynamic but this is not good architecture imao.

```
public List<dynamic> GetAllOrderViewModels()
{
    return _dbContext.Orders.Select(o => new 
    {
        OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
        OrderNumber = o.Id,
        ShippingAddress = o.ShipToAddress,
        Total = o.Total()
    }).ToList<dynamic>();
}
```

Is the correct approach to add specific Dtos to `ApplicationCore`, `Infrastructure` or is there something I'm missing?

The most similar I found was `BasketQueryService` but it only returns an `int`.

```
public class BasketQueryService : IBasketQueryService
{
    private readonly CatalogContext _dbContext;

    public BasketQueryService(CatalogContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This method performs the sum on the database rather than in memory
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="username"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<int> CountTotalBasketItems(string username)
    {
        var totalItems = await _dbContext.Baskets
            .Where(basket => basket.BuyerId == username)
            .SelectMany(item => item.Items)
            .SumAsync(sum => sum.Quantity);

        return totalItems;
    }
}
```

Given that the question is about `Clean architecture` I deemed it OK to be asked.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Application Core**
>
> The Application Core holds the business model, which
> includes entities, services, and interfaces. These interfaces include
> abstractions for operations that will be performed using
> Infrastructure, such as data access, file system access, network
> calls, etc. Sometimes services or interfaces defined at this layer
> will need to work with non-entity types that have no dependencies on
> UI or Infrastructure. These can be defined as simple Data Transfer
> Objects (DTOs).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#application-core

Given this documentation I created a `OrderDto` and placed it in `ApplicationCore` -> `Dto`.

```
namespace Microsoft.eShopWeb.ApplicationCore.Dto;
public class OrderDto
{

        private const string DEFAULT_STATUS = "Pending";

        public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset OrderDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Total { get; set; }
        public string Status => DEFAULT_STATUS;
        public Address ShippingAddress { get; set; }
}
```

Example in `EfRepository` even though something like `OrderQueryService` based on `BasketQueryService` would be better:

```
public List<OrderDto> GetAllOrderDtos()
{
    return _dbContext.Orders.Select(o => new OrderDto
    {
        OrderDate = o.OrderDate,
        OrderNumber = o.Id,
        ShippingAddress = o.ShipToAddress,
        Total = o.Total()
    }).ToList();
}
```